# Bug in while loop

Tags: loops, haskell

I can't figure out what the bug is in the toy `while` loop I wrote below. It works for one input, but hangs for other inputs. Here is the code - the while loop takes a vector, a predicate on vector, and transformation function on vector, and returns another vector:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

while :: Vector Int -> (Vector Int -> Bool) -> (Vector Int -> Vector Int) -> Vector Int
while v p f = go 0 v
      where go n x = if (p x) then go (n+1) (f x)
                              else x

test :: Vector Int -> Vector Int
test a = while a (\x -> (x!0) < 2) (\x -> U.map (+1) a)

main = print $ test (U.fromList [0])
```

This hangs on execution of `main`. On the other hand, if I change `test` to:

```
test a = while a (\x -> (x!0) < 1) (\x -> U.map (+1) a)
```

I get a termination with result (`ghci` output below):

```
λ: main
fromList [1]
```

I feel I must be missing something. I looked hard at the function, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It looks like predicate can't be executed more than twice.

BTW, it works with other types like `Int`.

```
   while :: Int -> (Int -> Bool) -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
    while i p f = go 0 i
          where go n x = if (p x) then go (n+1) (f x)
                                  else x

    test :: Int ->  Int
    test a = while a (\x -> x < 2) (\x -> x+1)

    main = print $ test 0
```

ghci output:

```
λ: main
2
```

`GHC version: 7.6.1`

`Vector version: 0.10.0.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
test a = while a (\x -> (x!0) < 1) (\x -> U.map (+1) a)
```

should be

```
test a = while a (\x -> (x!0) < 1) (\x -> U.map (+1) x)
```

or

```
test a = while a (\x -> (x!0) < 1) (U.map (+1))
```

Otherwise the function you are iterating ignores its argument.

---

Your loop increases a counter, but does not use it. You can remove it:

```
while v p f = go v
      where go x = if p x then go (f x) else x
```

Comment: aha, glad to see it was so simple!